# Why bevel modifier is not working?

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I'm trying to cut the edges/corners of the pillar that I built by using bevel modifier (pic. 1). Selected one vertex and tried with several  edges (to cut a straight line of corners). It does not work as I expected. I already tried:

- to select the object and merge the vertices by distance
- to delete some of them (worked in a weird way)
- somehow I managed to do something similar by pressing ctrl+b+v (pic.2) and even ctrl+b+c (pic. 3)??
- tried just ctrl+b command

By now, I already figured that my keypad is not working as it should, I cannot do many commands for example, I can't use numpad to zoom in on the object, I checked if the command is correct in view- navigation.
But I still hope that this issue is fixable.

Blender version: 3.5.1,
Pc: Mac Air,
My file: https://workupload.com/file/fLVcsjEKLJh

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: what do you mean when you say that it doesn't work as expected? You need to apply the scale, it stretches the bevel, also the selected pillar has overlapping vertices and you need to merge by distance or the bevel on work on some edges and vertices

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to screenshot the tutorial, to explain what I'm trying to do. :( Can you please specify, how should I apply the scale? Also, I tried to merge the vertices several times, and it didn't do much either.

Comment: To apply the scale, in Object mode press Ctrl A > Apply Scale

Comment: Didn't work:( Probably I will need to built them again, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Again, t's not clear what you're trying to do and why you think that it doesn't work, if I apply the scale and Merge by Distance it works fine with the objects in your scene, so maybe give more details in your original question

Comment: Just uploaded a picture of the pillar, and how it should look like. Hope it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: Do you mean you can't do what you show on picture 1? Because you actually can with your current file

Comment: Yes, I'm not managing to do that.

Comment: No, I haven't, will try to switch. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, seems that the version wasn't the problem:'((

Comment: OK it's not a version problem after all, but see the bevel I'm doing, it seems to work (after having merged by distance): https://www.zupimages.net/up/23/46/n90u.gif

Comment: Okay, tried that, but now, only the first bottom layer is affected, and other selected edges don't move

Comment: what do you call "layer"? Are you talking about the edges? If so, I don't know what you're doing wrong, it should work. Also, are you using the Bevel modifier or just the manual bevel (Ctrl B)?

Comment: Tried both, same thing

Comment: if you are familiar with Discord, come here: https://discord.gg/E6wXbR7A5S

Answer (score 1):

Alright i downloaded your file and did the following: edit mode, select all, merge by distance. This removed 83 overlapping vertices
[image]

Then i just applied a bevel modifier, default settings with 3 segments, set shading to smooth and it worked:
[image]

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Heres what i would do: apply the scale. Then try disabling the "clamp overlap" option in the Bevel modifier. Then you should see the bevel applied but maybe also some artifacts because its not clamped anymore. You could also try to set the Bevel mode to "percentage", that also does sometimes work.

Comment: Hey, "clamp overlap" was already disabled, and setting the mode to "percentage" did not help either. :/